# How to build private blockchain network using Hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger, corda

I am new to **Hyperledger**, I have brief knowledge about Ethereum. I want to create **private network** using Hyperledger. So, how can we create private network in Hyperledger and deploy the smart contract or **chain code** to that network ?

And also same thing I want to build using R3 Corda, so is it possible to do inside Corda ?

Can anyone have any reference link or steps for that ?

Comment: to setup the corda network refer documentation: https://docs.corda.net/setting-up-a-corda-network.html

Comment: And if I want to use Hyperledger then how to build private network ?

Answer (score 1):

As Kid101 mentions, you can set up a Corda network by following the instructions in https://docs.corda.net, and in particular https://docs.corda.net/setting-up-a-corda-network.html.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger includes multiple blockchain technologies, including Hyperledger Sawtooth.

For Sawtooth, here's a brief summary of the package installation steps and initial setup. This will install the Hyperledger Sawtooth software and setup a blockchain with 1 block (the "genesis" block, block 0):

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 8AA7AF1F1091A5FD
$ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://repo.sawtooth.me/ubuntu/1.0/stable xenial universe'
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y sawtooth
$ sawtooth keygen
$ sawset genesis
$ sudo -u sawtooth sawadm genesis config-genesis.batch
$ sudo sawadm keygen
```

Full details are at: https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/app_developers_guide/installing_sawtooth.html

There are also admin guides and tutorials to follow.  But this will get you started.